# Find minimum value and a target property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this:

```
var data = [
  { id: 537, name: "aBase" },
  { id: 1, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 8 } },
  { id: 2, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 10 } },
  { id: 3, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 5 } },
  { id: 4, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 2 } },
];
```

and I want the `id` of the `'aBase'` object and the min `y` of all of the `'aCourt'` objects. The output I want should be something like this:

```
result = [{id:537,y:2}]
```

My code so far is like this

```
let result = [];
data.map((item) => {
    if (item.name === "aBase") {
      if (!result[item.id] === item.id) {
        result[item.id] = item.id;
      }
    } else {
      if (item.name === "aCourt") {
        if (result[item.id] === item.aBaseId) {
          if (!result[item.id].y || result[item.id].y > item.rating.y) {
            result[item.id].y = item.rating.y;
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

How can I fix the code to produce the desired output?

Comment: both of the things can be separately calculated using forEach , dont complicate it with using other functions like map

Comment: Will the `aBase` element always be first in `data`? If so, you can just use 

`result = [{ id: data[0]['id'], y: Math.min(...data.slice(1).map(e => e.rating.y)) }]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should also work for an arbitrary number of elements in your array. It will combine the data of elements with the same `id` and 
`aBaseId`s into a common result object. The order of elements is immaterial.

```js
var data = [
  { id: 123, name: "aBase"},
  { id: 537, name: "aBase" },
  { id: 1, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 8 } },
  { id: 2, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 10 } },
  { id: 3, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 5 } },
  { id: 4, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 2 } },
  { id: 5, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 123, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 17 } },
  { id: 6, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 123, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 12 } }
];
var res=data.filter(c=>c.name=='aBase')
 .map(c=>({id:c.id, y: Math.min.apply(null,data.filter(e=>e.aBaseId==c.id).map(f=>f.rating.y))}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can do it with a condition to find your base and `Math.min` to find the lowest `e.rating.y`:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 537, name: "aBase" },
  { id: 1, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 8 } },
  { id: 2, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 10 } },
  { id: 3, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 5 } },
  { id: 4, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 2 } },
];

const res = data.reduce((a, e) => {
  if (e.name === "aBase") {
    a.id = e.id;
  }
  else {
    a.y = Math.min(a.y, e.rating.y);
  }
  
  return a;
}, {y: Infinity});

console.log(res);
```

Your expected output wraps this in a single-element array, but this seems unnecessary, so I've omitted it.

Another alternative is using `find` to collect the base, then `map` everything else to its `y` rating, then take the min. The downside is two passes.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 537, name: "aBase" },
  { id: 1, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 8 } },
  { id: 2, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 10 } },
  { id: 3, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 5 } },
  { id: 4, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 2 } },
];

const res = {
  id: data.find(e => e.name === "aBase").id,
  y: Math.min(...data.map(({rating}) => rating ? rating.y : Infinity))
};

console.log(res);
```

As pointed out in the comments, if you can guarantee `aBase` as the first element, then you can simplify the above code a bit:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 537, name: "aBase" },
  { id: 1, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 8 } },
  { id: 2, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 10 } },
  { id: 3, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 5 } },
  { id: 4, name: "aCourt", aBaseId: 537, rating: { x: 6.4, y: 2 } },
];

const res = {
  id: data[0].id,
  y: Math.min(...data.slice(1).map(({rating}) => rating.y))
};

console.log(res);
```